# How to adjust width of longtable (numeric values)

Tags: tables, longtable, adjustbox

Below is the code of my table. It has many columns, each of which has a numeric value. I would like to split this into many pages (that's why I'm using `longtable`) and fit it to page width (`tiny` font is still too big). I like the `adjustbox` package but it doesn't work with longtables. What is the alternative in that case? I don't want to format numbers, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{longtable}
    
\begin{document}

\begin{tiny}

\begin{longtable}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\

123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\

123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\


\end{longtable}
\end{tiny}

\end{document}
```

Comment: sorry code added

Comment: if you want to print this table, setup the table so that you can use a sensible, readable fontsize (at least \footnotesize). If the table is only meant for screen use a larger paperwidth (but consider to split the table too, nobody likes to have to scroll forever to see the data).

Comment: Your question seems to be duplicate  to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options.

Comment: never use adjustbox or resizebox on tables, with longtable it's a syntax error, but that is a feature, the fact that it doesn't error on `tabular` is unfortunate;

Comment: Are you really trying to typeset a table with 12 columns, each of which may contain numbers with up to nine digits? If, please provide a more realistic example of what you need to get done.

Comment: @Mico this is just an example. It often happens to me that table is just a slightly too wide to fit the page even with `tiny` font (most often with numeric values as above) and it would be great to find a solution . I'm using `adjustbox` package for one-page tables and for me it works fine but the problem is with multipage tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From all possibilities, which are listed in answer on [/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options) you should consider:

- rotate table to landscape orientatio,
- reduce font size to stil easy readable font size, for example `\small` or `\footnotesize`
- increase text area, for example determine 25mm margins (by `\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}`)

With implementation of this measures table will occupy 3 pages, from them the looks like that:

[image]

It is produce by MWE, which preamble is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}


\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}
    \small
\begin{longtable}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
% other table lines from your MWE
\end{longtable}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Is this solution acceptable to you? I'm affray, the you haven't much other options. To have `\tiny` font size  or even smaller for printed mater is very unfriendly to readers ...

Answer (score 1):

Your sample code leaves a lot of important points unaddressed. Such as, how wide are the margins? Assuming you're using US Letter paper with one inch margins all around, I can only suggest that you render the table in landscape format. I.e., something like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
    
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\small

\begin{longtable}{*{11}{c|}c}

123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
\dots & & & & & & & & & & \\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\

\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Huh, almost at the same time and suggested solution :-) . +1 of course!

Comment: @Zarko - Thanks! (I've upvoted your answer too. You should insert `\noindent` before `\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}`, though...)

Answer (score 1):

Never use adjustbox on tables, no good outcome can result. Always use a declared document font size such as `\small` to get consistent results.
`\tiny` isn't really suitable for extended blocks of text so `\footnotesize` is really the smallest you want to use.

You could use `landscape` as Mico showed, or if you can steal space from the margins:

[image]

from

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{longtable}
    
\begin{document}

\footnotesize
\setlength{\LTleft}{-3.5cm plus 1fill}
\setlength{\LTright}{-3.5cm plus 1fill}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}

\begin{longtable}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
```

But I would probably do

[image]

from

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{longtable}
    
\begin{document}


\begin{longtable}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
\caption{Data columns 1--6}\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\

 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\

 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\


\end{longtable}



\begin{longtable}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
\caption{Data columns 7--12}\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\

 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\

 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\
 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789 & 123456789\\


\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```